# Need to get image filename in folder by matching if file contain certain name

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

In the image folder, the filename is arranged by Country_State_Date.jpg. Example : Usa_LA_4_jul.jpg.  I need to get all the image filename which contain Usa. How should I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in isolated storage, you could get them with GetFileName() e.g.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    f.GetFileNames("Images/USA*");
}
```

If they are in your project directory, then I would recommend setting the build action to 'Embedded Resource' and then you can get them by doing something along the lines of

```
 Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 string[] allResources = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
 string[] usaResources = allResources.Where(a => a.Contains("USA")).ToArray(); 

 // get which ever stream you want from this collection
 Stream imageStream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(usaResources.First());
```

Then when you wanted to read the data from the file you just need to create a bitmap image with that stream as the image source.

```
   var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
   bitmapImage .SetSource(imageStream);
   img.Source = bitmapImage ;
```

Comment: @ggbanfill : The folder is not in IsolatedStorage. It is inside the project folder.

Comment: Updated to include instructions on how to get the image as an embedded resource.

Comment: Thank for the info for getting resources as embeded. How to I modify it to work for getting image files by matching filename with certain word as above from the image folder inside the projet. Thanks in advance.